# stored procedure not running, maybe bad job configuration

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs

i have a stored procedure, on a sql server, with the following code:

```
    USE [MASS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DossierEmailSend]    Script Date: 05/11/2019 17:36:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DossierEmailSend]
AS
 --Create a holding table for the dossiers that met the criteria

DECLARE @dossiers TABLE (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(100), col4 varchar(100));

 --Insert the dossiers that met the criteria

INSERT INTO @dossiers
SELECT no, nome, obrano, convert(varchar,datafinal) col4  
    FROM bo
    WHERE nmdos LIKE '%preço%'
    AND datafinal = DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))

 --Create a row check to determine whether to send the email or not

DECLARE @rows int;
SET @rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @dossiers)

 --Set the body elements

DECLARE @message varchar(1000);
-- declare the xml data to pass to the HTML body
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- body will hold the HTML formatted table in the email
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX);

 --Create the columns that will hold each row of data as xml

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT col1 AS 'td','',col2 AS 'td','', col3 AS 'td','', col4 AS 'td'
FROM @dossiers
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

 --Set the HTML for the body

SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Dossier Info</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> Num </th> <th> Nome </th> <th> Dossier </th> <th> Data de Fecho </th></tr>'

 --Stitch everything together, appending the HTML table

SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

SET NOCOUNT ON 

 --Check if any dossiers met the criteria

IF @rows > 0 
BEGIN

 --Send the email and append the data table to the body

EXEC dbo.uspSendEmail 'Encerramento Dossier Preços', 'ssantos@mass.pt', @body, NULL, 'filipeferreira@mass.pt'
SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
```

to run this procedure, i created a job, that fetches this procedure, but the fact is that it's not running. on the job properties, i have set:

on success action quit the job reporting success and on failure action the same thing. i really don't know if the mistake is here, any thoughts on this guys?

Comment: totally unclear what question you are asking.  "any thought on this guys" is not a question we can answer.

Comment: Does the procedure run when you run it manually in SSMS?  What **exactly** do you mean when you say "it's not running"?  What does the job history say for the job?  Why did you set both the "success" and "failure" actions to "quit job reporting success"?

Comment: what the procedure does is to check the validity (based on time) of some files. if it ends, if the it reaches the final day, it should send an email to the addresses that are there telling what has ended.

Comment: so, after all, i tried to run the procedure manually, but it did not send any e-mail, so i guess that's where my problem is...